# Sound Manager button to pause sound (with inline player)

Tags: jquery, audio, soundmanager2

I would like to make a button to pause all sounds that are playing on the page.

I am using the inline player but want to have a button to pause the sound in other places on the page (in the navbar)
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [soundManager2 API](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#api) you can pauseAll on the main soundManager object

```
soundManager.pauseAll();
```